# Get list item value from DragEventArgs

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to drag a listitem from a listbox onto a picture box.

The list item is a persons name. The value member of the list item is the ID of the people listed.

When I drop the list item onto the picture box I want to use the persons ID to query a photo and load that photo.

I can't seem to access the value though, only the name text, using e.Data.GetDataPresent where e is the DragEventArgs.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Sorry, but how did you implement drag and drop to PictureBox. As far as I see from documentation, PictureBox does not support AllowDrop property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to declare the selected value as a string and then pass this to the dodragdrop event properties.  this is done on the object you use the mousedown command to drag from

Answer (score 0):

to drag to a picturebox you have declare it on form load as picturebox1.allowdrop = true.  the intellisense doesn't show this option but it is valid